# CSS - material web components implementing drawer with the hero section

Tags: html, css, material-design

I have started working with [material web components](https://material.io/components/web/) on a new project for the first time. I am trying to use their persistent drawer with the hero section on a page, where I also have a toolbar.

The template looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--persistent mdc-typography">
    <nav class="mdc-drawer__drawer">
      <header class="mdc-drawer__header">
        <div class="mdc-drawer__header-content">
          Header here
        </div>
      </header>
      <nav id="icon-with-text-demo" class="mdc-drawer__content mdc-list">
        <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>Inbox
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
          <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">star</i>Star
        </a>
      </nav>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <header class="mdc-toolbar mdc-toolbar--fixed demo-toolbar">
    <div class="mdc-toolbar__row">
      <section class="menu mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-start">
        <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__menu-icon">menu</a>
        <span class="mdc-toolbar__title">Title</span>
      </section>
      <section class="mdc-toolbar__section">
        Section aligns to center.
      </section>
      <section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
        <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon" aria-label="Download" alt="Download">file_download</a>
        <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon" aria-label="Print this page" alt="Print this page">print</a>
        <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon" aria-label="Bookmark this page" alt="Bookmark this page">bookmark</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="page-content">
     <div class="landing-page-hero">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have much css, I have copied from their [demo](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/drawer/persistent-drawer.html) the css for the `page-content` and added css for the `landing-page-her`o:

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
.page-content {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.landing-page-hero {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 45vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('/img/hero-image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 60%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: $white;
}
```

For some reason the drawer won't open when I have a `div` element with the `id="app"` that wraps the whole page. I am using this `div` element to mount `Vue`.

So, if I remove this element, then the drawer opens but only above the image:

[image]

But, like I said, I need this element to mount `Vue`, and when I have it then  the `drawer` is not visible on clicking the `menu`, and the `hero` is not immediately below the `toolbar`, there looks like their is `margin-bottom` from the `drawer` that pushes it further down.

[image]

How can I make this work? So, that I have a toolbar with the drawer and a hero section immediately below the toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the js issue part with requiring the material package after mounting the Vue on #app element:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

window.mdc = require('material-components-web/dist/material-components-web')
window.mdc.autoInit();
require('./material/drawer');
```

And, then in the css, I have set the `display` of #app to `display: flex`, and then it worked.